# What are the parameters should i test to evaluate the performance of a vector database in my web app

Tags: database, vector

In the context of a project i need to implement a vector database in my webapp and evaluate its performance. Therefore i need to know what are the performance metrics that I need to test.

I would appreciate any help regarding my question.